# Git LFS Missing Files

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-lfs

My company has a Git repo that supports LFS.

The LFS was set up before I joined.

I believe person set it up didn't tell other people. So over time, there are missing LFS objects here and there.

That brings it to today.

I was tasked with moving the current repo to a new repo.
However, when I try to fetch and push the LFS objects, there are missing LFS objects. Nobody knows where those are anymore.

Now I don't care about LFS in the new repo.

Is there anyway I can migrate my current repo to the new repo without LFS?

I want the actual files to be moved, not the LFS pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

My approach was to sanitize the repo by [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) and then push the clean repo to the new server.

Here an example:

```sh
git clone --mirror git://some-server.com/some-dirty-repo.git
java -jar bfg.jar --delete-files /some-dirty-path/some-dirty-files-pattern

cd some-dirty-repo.git
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now --aggressive

git push
```

Please, tell me if it worked for you too.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it tonight. Does this push all the branches and history to the new repo?

Comment: Yes, you have to issue git push --all and git push --tags.

Comment: Interesting. I did `git push  new-origin --all` but the new repo still have issue with the missing lfs objects. At this point, I'm thinking I'll find a way to remove lfs and download the files then push them to the new repo.

Comment: You have to push the repository pruned by *bfg** in order to ge a clean copy. I think you do some training with this tool. :) Good luck!